# RPi - Water pump control using MOSFET

Tags: mosfet, circuit-design, opto-isolator

I am working on a project where I need to control this [water pump](https://www.digikey.be/nl/products/detail/dfrobot/FIT0563/8827828) using a Raspberry Pi 3B+.

Currently, I've chosen the [IRLD014PBF N-channel MOSFET](https://www.digikey.be/nl/products/detail/vishay-siliconix/IRLD014PBF/812481) to drive this water pump. For added protection to my RPi GPIO, I've decided to incorporate the [TLP620-2X opto-coupler](https://www.digikey.be/nl/products/detail/isocom-components-2004-ltd/TLP620-2X/5037044) into the circuit.

[image: RPi MOSFET water pump circuit]

I have attached the schematic for review and would appreciate feedback on the component selection. Specifically, I am unsure about the chosen MOSFET and opto-coupler, and the necessity of resistors R1 and R2 (would like to know if they are required, as well as recommendations for their values).

Comment: Add a resistor between the gate and ground (1k Ohm).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should consider using this modified circuit: -

[image]

Regarding the MOSFET (rated at just over 1 amps continuous), it's unclear what current the pump takes despite reading the data sheet. I suspect that the MOSFET may overheat if you don't choose something with a little more capability.

OK, I've re-read the data sheet and, it seems to imply the pump takes between 65 mA and 500 mA. However, if the pump got blocked (quite a common thing) then the current may exceed the rating for the MOSFET.

Comment: Thank you for the modified circuit!

Regarding the water pump, I may be implementing an additional circuit for current sensing, to prevent the current from exceeding the MOSFET's ratings.

As for the need for a heatsink on the MOSFET, I've completed the following calculations: with a current consumption of 750mA and an Rds of 0.2 ohms, the power dissipation is 0.1125 W. Given the MOSFET's thermal resistance of 120°C/W, the temperature is expected to rise by approximately 13.5°C.

Do you think it would be adequate to operate without a heatsink?

Comment: @Engineering007 I personally think you are pushing it too hard and that a MOSFET with lower on resistance would be a more reliable choice (maybe 0.1 ohms with a Vgs of 5 volts). It's just a little too close to the "unreliable" area to make me convinced.

Comment: Regarding the heatsink, because the localized temperature around the MOSFET rises (due to power dissipation) you ought to factor that in. I mean, I don't know what external ambient temperature you are expecting or, how the MOSFET is enclosed to make a judgement call on this.

Comment: Agreed, the initial MOSFET choice was somewhat optimistic. Based on your advice, I've opted for the [IRLD024PBF](https://www.digikey.be/en/products/detail/vishay-siliconix/IRLD024PBF/812492), featuring an Rds of 0.1 ohms @ 5V and a higher continuous rating of 2.5A (up from 1.7A). This MOSFET dissipates about 56mW @ 750mA, resulting in a ΔT of 6.75 °C.

Regarding the electronic enclosure, intended for an RC submarine, it's completely sealed without airflow, yet the surrounding water may provide a cooling effect.

Comment: I feel more comfortable about that choice but, for a sub maybe you should have an internal temperature monitor that shuts down stuff should it rise too high. I guess if it's a metal body it'll be alright.